# Alternative to Identity column

Tags: sql-server-2008, identity-column

we have Orders table with an identity column (OrderID) but our order number is composed by OrderType (2 chars), OrderYear (2 chars) and OrderID (6 chars), totally 10 chars (i.e. XX12123456).
This counter has limitations: we can arrive to identity 999999 as OrderID . Next order will have ID composed by 7 chars. Obviously we cannot ave duplicates order ids.

So we have created a table prefilled with progressive OrderID and OrderYear (from 100000 to 999999, order year from 12 to 16, for instance): this stored procedure begins a transacation with SERIALIZABLE isolation level, take first order id not used, update it as used and commit the transaction.

Being our Orders table, i'm worried about deadlocks on executing order id calculation stored procedure or duplicated orderids.

I'll test this with a console application that create multiple concurrency threads and try to extract orderids simulating a production load.

Doubts are:

- Exists another method to simulate an identity column safely?
- May consider usage of triggers?
- May consider differente isolation level?
- Other ideas? :D

Thanks!

[EDIT]

After googling and reading a bunch of MSDN documentation, i've found many examples showing how managing errors and dealocks and approaching a type of automatic reply directly from SP, as follow:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Ordine_GetOrderID]

@AnnoOrdine AS NVARCHAR(2) = NULL OUTPUT,
@IdOrdine AS INT = NULL OUTPUT

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @retry AS INT
SET @retry = 2

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

WHILE (@retry > 0)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION OrderID   

    SELECT TOP 1 @AnnoOrdine = AnnoOrdine, @IdOrdine = IdOrdine
    FROM ORDINI_PROGRESSIVI --WITH (ROWLOCK)
    WHERE Attivo = 1
    --ORDER BY AnnoOrdine ASC, IDOrdine ASC 

    UPDATE ORDINI_PROGRESSIVI WITH (UPDLOCK)
    SET Attivo = 0
    WHERE AnnoOrdine = @AnnoOrdine AND IdOrdine = @IdOrdine

    IF ISNULL(@IdOrdine, '') = '' OR ISNULL(@AnnoOrdine,'') = ''
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Deadlock', 1, 1205)
    END

    SET @retry = 0

    COMMIT TRANSACTION OrderID  

    SELECT @AnnoOrdine AS AnnoOrdine, @IdOrdine AS IdOrdine 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF (ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205)
        SET @retry = @retry - 1;
    ELSE
        SET @retry = -1;

    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;       

END CATCH
```

END

This approach reduce deadlocks (absent at all) but sometimes i got EMPTY output parameter.
Tested with 30 contemporary threads (so, 30 customers processes that insert orders at the same moment)

Here a debug log with query duration, in milliseconds: http://nopaste.info/285f558758.html

Enough robust for production?

Comment: Is order type separate from the order ID - ie: can you have AA120123456 and AB120123456 ?

Comment: yes, we prefer to have different id by order type

Comment: SQL Server **2012** has `SEQUENCE` objects which allow you to define sequences of numbers, totally independently of any table. You could setup one sequence for each order type you need, and then retrieve those values before you insert the rows.

Comment: Ops! i dont pay attention to "2012" (and you have bold it :D)

We use 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If you do discover that the current solution is creating problems, and it's possible that it won't, then an alternative would be to have a table for each id type you want to create with an identity column and a dummy field

ie:

```
 ABtypeID (ABID int identity(1,1), dummy varchar(1))
```

You can then insert a record into this table and use the built in functions to retrieve an identity.

ie

```
insert ABTypeID (dummy) values (null)
select Scope_Identity()
```

You can delete from these tables as and when you like, and truncacte them at year end to reset the id counters.

You can even wrap the insert in a transaction that gets rolled back - the identity value is not affected by the rollback

Comment: prefer to avoid to reset identity manually.

I'll try SEQUENCE approch, i can set min and max value, built-in cache functionality and auto cycle. It's perfect!

Comment: @ShArDiCk If you have SQL 2012, it is. :)